# Is using GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_* or GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_* for GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER considered erroneous if MIP maps have not been generated?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have a feeling this is one of those situations that will depend on the driver implementation since this scenario is not described in the OpenGL specification. However, I'm hoping that someone will know if using GL_(LINEAR/NEAREST)_ MIPMAP_* without generating MIP maps would be treated the same as using GL_(LINEAR/NEAREST)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define "without any active MIP textures"? I'm not sure how you would, since there's no such thing as a "mip texture" (a texture *contains* mipmaps, but mipmaps are not textures).

If you mean that you did not create a full mipmap pyramid, then it depends on how you set up your `GL_TEXTURE_BASE/MAX_LEVEL`s. If you properly used these to tell OpenGL you only had one mipmap level, then you'll be fine. If you used [`glTexStorage`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glTexStorage2D) to create your texture's storage, and you only told it to create one mipmap, again you'll be fine.

But if none of those apply, then OpenGL defaults to the least useful thing (per its usual idiocy): it sets the `GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL` level to 1000. Which means it's going to expect you to have defined mipmaps.

According to (desktop) OpenGL, a texture with mipmap filtering where the `BASE/MAX_LEVEL`s refer to mipmaps that are not defined is not "texture complete". OpenGL defines that the value you get for a texture access against a non-complete texture is (0, 0, 0, 1).

In short, set your `BASE/MAX_LEVEL` properly and you won't have to worry. ***ALWAYS DO THIS.***

Comment: Sorry for the bad terminology. Basically, what I meant was, if you use  GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_* without a call to `glGenerateMipMap`, will OpenGL treat it like GL_LINEAR. I think I got it. Thanks!

Comment: @user8709: "*I think I got it.*" **No, you did not.** You do not *have* to call `glGenerateMipmap`. You can manually upload mipmaps if you want. The point is to ***set your `BASE/MAX_LEVEL` correctly always***. Every time you create a texture and bind it, *immediately* make two glTexParameter calls to set the `BASE/MAX_LEVEL` to what you intend for them to be.

Comment: Yeah *I got it*. FYI, OpenGL ES 2.0 requires a full MIP map pyramid if you use MIP mapping. It does not support the `GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL` parameter. Support was added in ES 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, all the non-generated mipmap levels will default to black.

So if you have a texture displayed at 1:1 resolution, and progressively zoom out, it will fade to black as soon as the 1rst mipmap is used.

I think this is the behaviour at least on NVIDIA and AMD; I never tried on powervr (since you're mentioning opengl-es).